How to Validate File Content in ASP.NET Core (C#) to Prevent Misleading Extensions?
I'm working on file upload validation in an ASP.NET Core application using C#. I need to validate the content of an uploaded file before saving it, rather than relying solely on its extension. For instance, I have files with a .abc extension that should contain text content. I want to ensure that a file claiming to be .abc actually contains valid text, as someone could potentially rename an executable file to .abc and upload it. How can I implement this validation effectively?

You can check the mime time, how you are currently implemented your code? So that it might be taken a look and easy to assist.

When reading the fine stream, you can check the  string content = reader.ReadToEnd(); and check  foreach (char c in content) if the content containing any text characters within.

This question is similar to: C# - Check if File is Text Based. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Doesn't the MIME type depend on file extensions?

That's true, in order be more exact, we need to check, extension, content and then if the contents are valid text, you can play with my example and yes, if a programmer's call how many level of validation wants to set, actually lot of ways we can achieve that. I have splited the methods in smaller part to make it readable. You can refactor at your preferable way. For other kind of mime type relavant validation going on. I just only shown the text validation.

Hello @Md.MustafizurRahman is there anything I could assist you on this, don't hasitate to ask if you need any further help, I would be glad to assist.

Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you for your solution—it worked perfectly! Could you also guide me on how to validate a CSV file? My CSV files don't follow a specific structure, so I need a way to check if they are valid CSV files, similar to how you would validate a text file.

Hello @Md.MustafizurRahman thanks for your response. As we solely focused on cheking text file validation on this thread so in order to keep this as it is, could you please post a new question along the sample data which mostly your csv file consist of, therefore, I take a look how I could assist you there.

But in general, I would check extension, column , rows if those are correct and no malformed data. But it would depends how I am allowing the user to insert. In inverse scenario, I could control the format and enforce user to submit the csv accoridngly.


I need to validate the content of an uploaded file before saving it,
rather than relying solely on its extension

Well, in order to do that you can check the file Stream after checking the extension.
With the file stream you can read the file content by using reader.ReadToEnd().
If you need  more granular inspection if the containing file has any text at all, then you could execute the loop other the content to check if that containing valid text.
Let's have a look in practice, how we could achieve that:
Upload Controller Action:
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
    }

    // Checking file extension
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
    if (fileExtension != ".txt")
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid file extension.");
    }

    //I'm reading file content
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //First Validation for file content
        if (!IsValidTextFile(stream))
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid file content.");
        }
        
    }

    // If you have any other logic can set here

    return Ok("File uploaded successfully.");
}

Check the file content from file stream:
private bool IsValidTextFile(Stream stream)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //You can perform additional content validation if needed
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Here I am checking for text content in more granular steps
            return IsTextContent(content);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Check if the file contains text:
private bool IsTextContent(string content)
{
    foreach (char c in content)
    {
        if (char.IsControl(c) && c != '\r' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Note: As you can see here, I am checking that the content of the file consists of valid text characters by filtering out control characters except for commonly used whitespace control characters (\r, \n, \t).
Output:
My text text file containing following valuie:






